# LightGallery all html5 videos are playing at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lightgallery

I have used [lightGallery](http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/demos/html5-videos.html) plugin to play youtube, vimeo, and html5 videos. When a user clicks the image videos should play automatically. 
 Please check the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p1aw7utk/112/), It's working fine. But the problem is if there are two html5 videos both are playing at the same time. Youtube videos are not like that. When you click the image one youtube video will play at a time and when you slide to next video, the previous video will pause and the new video will play. But html5 all videos are playing at the same time. Please help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#html5-videos').lightGallery({});
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 220px;
  height: 150px;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  display: initial;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/lightgallery/css/lightgallery.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lightgallery/1.2.6/js/lightgallery-all.min.js"></script>
<!-- Hidden video div -->
<div style="display:none;" id="video1">
  <video class="lg-video-object lg-html5" controls preload="none">
        <source src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/videos/video4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</div>
<div style="display:none;" id="video2">
  <video class="lg-video-object lg-html5" controls preload="none">
        <source src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/videos/video2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
         Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</div>
<ul id="html5-videos">
  <!-- Youtube video -->
  <li class="selectoritem video width100" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yp0a1oZQRVM" data-sub-html="Youtube video first">
    <a href="" class="thumbnail width100 portimgfullwidth" style="background-image: url(https://img.youtube.com/vi/yp0a1oZQRVM/0.jpg);">
      <img class="img-responsive widthauto hide" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/yp0a1oZQRVM/0.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="selectoritem video width100" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g4o8jfO92CI" data-sub-html="Youtube video second">
    <a href="" class="thumbnail width100 portimgfullwidth" style="background-image: url(https://img.youtube.com/vi/g4o8jfO92CI/0.jpg;">
      <img class="img-responsive widthauto hide" src="https://img.youtube.com/vi/g4o8jfO92CI/0.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <!-- Html 5 video -->
  <li data-sub-html="video caption1" data-html="#video1">
    <img src="https://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/videos/h-video3-poster.jpg" />
  </li>
  <li data-sub-html="video caption2" data-html="#video2">
    <img src="http://sachinchoolur.github.io/lightGallery/static/img/thumb-v-y-1.jpg" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on GitHub.

- https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/issues/598
- https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery/issues/524

I updated [lg-video.js](https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lg-video/blob/master/dist/lg-video.js) and it's working fine.